# onclick de un recyclerview en un fragmento

Tags: android

¿Cómo podría hacer para que el onclick del recycler funcione en un fragmento? Ya que intento y no hace nada, me funciona normal en un activity, pero no en fragmento.

Este es código de clase adapter.

```
public class AdaptadorCL extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdaptadorCL.Tienda> implements View.OnClickListener {
   private View.OnClickListener listener;

   List<listafac> datos;
   public AdaptadorCL(List<listafac> datos) {
    this.datos = datos;
}
@NonNull
@Override
public AdaptadorCL.Tienda onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View v= LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.mpedidoscliente,viewGroup,false);
    v.setOnClickListener(this);
    AdaptadorCL.Tienda holder= new AdaptadorCL.Tienda(v);
    return holder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull AdaptadorCL.Tienda tienda, int position) {
    listafac perfil= datos.get(position);
    tienda.txttienda.setText(perfil.getNombretienda());
    tienda.txtfecha.setText(perfil.getFechayhora());
    tienda.txttotalf.setText(perfil.getSubtotal());
    tienda.txthora.setText(perfil.getEstado());

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return datos.size();

}
public void setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener listener){
    this.listener=listener;
}
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (listener!=null){
        listener.onClick(v);
    }

}
public static class Tienda extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    TextView txttienda,txtfecha,txttotalf,txthora,txtcod;
  //  ImageView txtimgen;

    public Tienda(View itemView){
        super(itemView);
        txttienda=(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.a1);
        txtfecha=(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.a2);
        txttotalf=(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.a3);
        txthora=(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.a4);


    }

  }
}
```

Y este del fragmento:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tab1c, container, false);
    rv=(RecyclerView)v.findViewById(R.id.pedidoclient);
    rv.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getContext(),1));
    subir=(Button)v.findViewById(R.id.subir);

    datos= new ArrayList<>();
    adapter=new AdaptadorCL(datos);
    rv.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), Gespedido.class);
            intent.putExtra("codC",datos.get(rv.getChildAdapterPosition(v)).getCoddetalle());
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

Comment: La mejor opción es crear una interfaz con el evento. Tu fragment debe implementar esta interfaz y cuando se realize el evento de click en tu lista, se notificará en tu fragment. Puedes revisar el siguiente ejemplo: Adapter = https://github.com/RaulitoGC/Technology-Store-App/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/rguzman/techstore/presentation/category/CategoryAdapter.java Fragment = https://github.com/RaulitoGC/Technology-Store-App/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/rguzman/techstore/presentation/category/CategoryListFragment.java

Comment: Estas seguro de que el método `onClick`, implementado en el adaptador, esta funcionando?